# Все элементы, родитель которых - корневой

Tags: sql, mysql

Есть таблица с такой структурой:

```
gid    // id
name   // название
parent // родитель, ссылается на gid, если 0 - то корневой элемент
```

Мне необходимо, **найти все дочерние элементы у корневого элемента**.

Написал вот такой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM `group` WHERE parent IN (SELECT gid FROM `group` WHERE parent = 0)
```

Нутром чую, что запрос не оптимальный, т.к. подозреваю что встроенный SELECT будет выполнятся для каждого gid-а.

Какой есть более оптимальный вариант поиска?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  SELECT g1.* FROM `group` AS g1
  JOIN `group` AS g2 ON g1.parent=g2.gid AND g2.parent=0
```

Comment: Исправил ваш запрос:

    SELECT g1.* FROM `group` AS g1
    JOIN `group` AS g2 ON g1.parent=g2.gid AND g2.parent=0